# Why does `read -r` still only get the first word of each line?

Tags: bash, scripts

This question is related to [my older one here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988403/bash-pass-command-output-to-function-in-realtime).

After I finally found out how to bypass the output of git into a function I have now another issue. Using

```
git clone --progress XYZ &> git_clone.file
```

writes as expected

```
Cloning to 'someRepository' ...
remote: Counting objects: 2618, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 2618 (delta 2), reused 12 (delta 1), pack-reused 2603
Received objects: 100% (2618/2618), 258.95 MiB | 4.39 MiB/s, Done.
Resolving Differences auf: 100% (1058/1058), Done.
Check Connectivity ... Done.
```

into `git_clone.file`.

Now I don't want to redirect the output to a file but to a function so I use

```bsh
function PrintInfo(){
    tput el
    echo $1
    <Print ProgressBar> 
    #For further details about this see 
    # https://askubuntu.com/questions/988403/bash-pass-command-output-to-function-in-realtime
}

git clone --progress XYZ |& {
    while read -r line
    do
        PrintInfo $line
    done
}
```

Now I would expect to get

```
Cloning to 'someRepository' ...
remote: Counting objects: 2618, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 2618 (delta 2), reused 12 (delta 1), pack-reused 2603
Received objects: 100% (2618/2618), 258.95 MiB | 4.39 MiB/s, Done.
Resolving Differences auf: 100% (1058/1058), Done.
Check Connectivity ... Done.
```

printed line by line and at the bottom my progressbar as described in [my other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988403/bash-pass-command-output-to-function-in-realtime). But instead I only get

```
Cloning
remote:
remote:
Received
...
```

and so on. I already tried all forms of `IFS` like

```bsh
... while IFS= read -r ...

... while IFS='' read -r ...

... while IFS="\n" read -r ...
```

but none of them solves this issue.

**How can I read the complete line of the output?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is *word splitting*.  To solve it, replace:

```
PrintInfo $line
```

With:

```
PrintInfo "$line"
```

#### Explanation

Consider:

```
PrintInfo $line
```

Before executing, `PrintInfo`, the shell will expand `$line` and perform both *word splitting* and *pathname expansion*.

Let's take a simple example, starting by defining a function:

```
$ PrintInfo() { echo "1=$1 2=$2 3=$3"; }
```

Now, let's execute the function:

```
$ line="one two three"
$ PrintInfo $line
1=one 2=two 3=three
```

In the above, *word splitting* caused `PrintInfo` to see three arguments.

If you want `PrintInfo` to see just one argument, use:

```
$ PrintInfo "$line"
1=one two three 2= 3=
```

Pathname expansion is also a potential problem.  Consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3
```

Now, let's run our version of `PrintInfo` again:

```
$ line='file?'
$ PrintInfo $line
1=file1 2=file2 3=file3
```

Because `?` is a valid glob character, the shell looks to replace `file?` with filenames.  To prevent that surprise, use double-quotes:

```
$ PrintInfo "$line"
1=file? 2= 3=
```

#### Summary

Except in cases where you explicitly want *word splitting* or *pathname expansion*, **shell variables should always be inside double-quotes**.

Comment: @derHugo Be careful.  That's not a full solution.  Without the double-quotes, `PrintInfo $line` is still subject to _pathname expansion_.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: note that you _also_ need to quote the `$1` inside the function, otherwise you'll get the same splitting and globbing issues there. (it's not that obvious with `echo`, but it will still trash whitespace inside the variable)